# Select Null statement, Is it possible?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a Java application which uses the log in mechanism, to test this, I am using a

> SELECT loginname FROM TABLE WHERE password="abc".

This is actually selecting a tuple from the table, I pass this into the result statement rs and then test for rs.next() and if it's true, then the entered username and password is correct.

I just had a question, is it possible to run a SELECT statement which returns no data but still marks the tuple? i.e. The query should return a set of rows equivalent to the number of matches, but they should all be null. I do not want to use COUNT and other functions. I just wanted to know, whether this is technically possible?

e.g.

> SELECT NONE FROM TABLE WHERE password="abc".

**Edit:** I am using MySQL

Comment: `SELECT NULL AS X FROM TABLE WHERE password="abc".` would work in SQL Server. `X` would be typed as `int`. I don't see the advantage of doing this though. Or did you mean a result set with rows with zero columns?

Comment: This is a really awful idea, please don't do this.

Comment: I know it's an awful idea but this would make anyone trying to read the memory for values returned by the sql very hard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is this what you need

```
SELECT null FROM  table where password= 'abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what sql server you're using, but in sqlite3, postgresql and mysql, you can run queries like `select '' from table where password='abc';` which will return 1 row containing an null string per result found.